# No description of attributes in Get Diagnostic Logs in Azure DevOps REST API

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I am not able to debug the value of source and entryId in List Diagnostic logs in following Azure DevOps REST API:

https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/notification/diagnosticlogs/{source}/entries/{entryId}?api-version=5.0-preview.1

Answer (score 1):

> No description of attributes in Get Diagnostic Logs in Azure DevOps REST API

Indeed, I also could not debug the value of `source` and `entryId` directly. After a painful time, I found a workaround for this issue. Please check following content:

To test this API, we need [enable subscription logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/howto-use-subscription-logging?view=azure-devops#enabling-subscription-logging):

> 1. Enable diagnostics for your organization by entering this URL in your browser:
>
>    `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_notifications?diagnostics=true`
> 2. When this completes, the option Enable Diagnostics appears in the subscription context menu

Then create some build pipelines, so that we could get the notifications.

According to the document [View subscription diagnostic logs for notification delivery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/howto-use-subscription-logging?view=azure-devops#view-subscription-diagnostic-logs-for-notification-delivery):

```
https://{organization}/_apis/notification/DiagnosticLogs/{event ID}/entries?startTime={date}&endTime={date}

event ID is a96d6177-beef-477a-a2ee-2c31433214d0 for any other event type
```

So, I use the event ID as source in the API and set the value of `{entryId}` as null.

Now, my Azure DevOps REST API is:

```
https://dev.azure.com/mycustomorganization/_apis/notification/DiagnosticLogs/a96d6177-beef-477a-a2ee-2c31433214d0/entries/?startTime=2019-01-01&endTime=2019-02-16&api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

And I could get the result by postman:

[image]

Note: As test, it seems we need also give the URI Parameters `startTime` and `endTime`, otherwise, we could not get the result.

Personally, this document is not perfect yet, thank you for your contribution to the optimization of this product. Hope the workaround helps you.